# How to get the version of a installed package using ocamlfind or opam?

Tags: opam, ocamlfind

In my configure script, I need to check the installed version of a package `<package>` using `ocamlfind` or `opam`. How do I get this information?

Answer (score 0):

#### Using ocamlfind: `ocamlfind query -format %v <package>`

This information is not directly available when running `ocamlfind query --help`, but it is available with `ocamlfind query -help-format`, which displays it among the other format options:

> ```
> Formats for -format strings:
>     ...
>     %v         version
>     ...
> ```

#### Using opam: `opam info -f installed-version <package>`

It returns `--` when the package is not installed.

This comes from `opam info --help`:

> ```
>   -f FIELDS, --field=FIELDS
>        Only display the values of these fields. Fields can be selected
>        among name, version, package, synopsis, synopsis-or-target,
>        description, <field>:, installed-version, pin, source-hash,
>        opam-file, all-installed-versions, available-versions,
>        all-versions, repository, installed-files, vc-ref, depexts.
>        Multiple fields can be separated with commas, in which case field
>        titles will be printed; the raw value of any opam-file field can be
>        queried by suffixing a colon character (:), e.g. --field=depopts:.
> ```